# Create ear file in Jdeveloper from jpr and jws project

Tags: ejb, ear, jdeveloper

I am currently working on Jdeveloper IDE, a project already is being setup by someone else and he is no longer with organization. 
When start  embeded server it start the server with the application which ejb 2.0 application. I am strugling to creating an ear file from the source code in Jdeveloper. 
I have google a lot but not able to find the solution. Please suggest me solution. I will appriciate if someone provide me alternate solution as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a deployment profile for your project (file->new->Deployment profile).
The exact steps depend on the version of JDeveloper you are using - you can try posting this on the JDeveloper discussion forum on OTN.